# Looping through output of docker bash command

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to loop through a docker bash command like this:
`sudo docker exec -it my-container bash -c "cd sites && ls" > output.txt`
which gives me expected output, when I loop through it as: `cat output.txt | while read line do echo "abcd${line}def"; done`
it gives me output as:

```
defdfile1
defdfile2
```

in short it is overlapping after file name
If I do all this without the docker command like only ls on my host it works fine, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the contents of the *output.txt* in second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `-t` flag docker outputs to standard out with added carriage return character.
It shows as `^M` with `cat -vte output.txt`. (`-v`, `--show-nonprinting` shows non printing characters using ^ or M- notation)

This carriage return breaks the formatting and the lines are not processed correctly. Remove the `-t` flag from the command to get the correct result.